# What is `ANY`, and how does it differ from `Any` ?

Tags: generics, types, julia, jit

In recent 0.5 nightlies of Julia I have started noticing type parameters named `ANY`, constrained to be subtypes of `Any`.
Which is of-course always true, as all types are subtypes of `Any`

For example:

```
serialize(s::SerializationState, x::ANY<:Any) at serialize.jl:468
show(io::IO, x::ANY<:Any) at show.jl:85
methods(f::ANY<:Any) at reflection.jl:258
methods(f::ANY<:Any, t::ANY<:Any) at reflection.jl:247
```

So what is going on?
Is this some kind of trick to encourage the compiler to generate specialized functions as it JITs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ANY` is a hack to hint to the compiler that it should not specialize on an argument. Otherwise the compiler will consider specializing functions on the specific types of all arguments they gets called with, which in some cases could end up being a lot of unnecessary code generation. It's kind of a dirty hack, and a more general mechanism for this would be better, but it gets the job done.

Comment: So the opposite of what I thought, thanks.
Is that hard coded to the keyword "ANY"? Or is that what will happen if ever I say `function foo{T<:Any}(bar::T)` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you look through base Julia's codebase, you can see that all the uses of `ANY` are just `x::ANY` on some function argument. I wouldn't count on `ANY` working in any other usage since it's a hack and ultimately to be replaced by something more general.